# Charge buildup in photoelectric experiment

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Suppose I have a simple discharge tube to demonstrate photoelectric effect.There is potential difference across the electrodes i.e, 0V.Now if I shine suitable frequency radiation to knock off electrons say 100 per second.Surely all 100 would not reach collector plates(say 50 electrons reaches).That means 100 electrons were removed from emitter but 50 returned back.Would not that mean a positive cahrge buildup on emmitter plate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shine a monochromatic light on the emitter plate of a photoelectric vacuum tube which is not connected to a circuit, a very small fraction of the electrons which absorb photons will break loose from the emitter and strike the collector.  The emitter will become positive and the collector negative.  The potential difference builds until the resulting electric field can prevent the electrons from reaching the the collector, and will depend on the frequency of the incoming photons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But the buildup would be short lived as the metal would extract electrons from the environment.